# regarding log4view file receiver

Tags: log4net, logfile, log4view

I am trying to open old files which are logged long time ago but I am not sure with which logging framework but it does seem like log4net because the files have date, thread and a message basically. Now the problem is log4view receiver cannot view the file. Is log4view specific for log4net files only or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is not written with the xml format, then you need to know the exact pattern that was used, so that Log4View can open them. Futhermore you should check the `Read whole file` checkbox.

Comment: thanks Stefan.. i will find out the exact pattern but some of the files contain a line like this ------------------- (the whole line contains hyphen) can this be handled by log4view or do i need to remove such lines from the files???

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it would ignore these lines

Comment: Thanks alot Stefan. It worked well now i can read the files with log4view.